# Domain authentication in Objectgears

Tags: objectgears

I would like to use Microsoft Active Directory to control user access rights in Objectgears. Where can I set this? If I select a person I can assign him a role but I would rather want the application checks his membership in the MS AD group which I have filled in the role.

Answer (score 0):

These are two things actually. The domain authentication is set in the web.config file in parameter authentication mode. The two options are:
     authentication mode="Forms" 
     authentication mode="Windows"

The latter one will ensure users do not need to enter user name and password but their identity will be taken over from their Windows.

Parameter AssignRoleToUser, if set to True, makes assignment of users to roles in ObjectGears. If you want to take over membership from MS AD groups, setit False and make sure that for each role that you have defined in Objectgears you also fill in name of the MS AD group in the field Name in the system.

Here is description of the Role definition: http://doc.objectgears.cz/Help.aspx?H=roledetail
Here is overview of access control in ObjectGears: http://doc.objectgears.cz/Help.aspx?H=a_access_control